# Is there My Music Player Notifcation Pause and Play Button Not Working But Music Stop and Play In Main Activity

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I am creating Music Player All Functionality Working fine But My Notification bar Play and Pause Button Not changing when i press in notification pause button but music is stop and also again click on notification pause button then also start music but not change the button

**Notification Code**

```
public static void  customBigNotification(Context context, String sname){


    RemoteViews expandView=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.status_bar_expanded);
    expandView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name,sname);

    NotificationCompat.Builder nc=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID);
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notifyIntent=new Intent(context,Player.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
    nc.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    nc.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.apollo_holo_dark_play);
    nc.setAutoCancel(true);
    nc.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
    nc.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    nc.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
    nc.setVibrate(new long[]{00});

    nc.setContentTitle("Music Player");
    nc.setContentText("Audio Control");
    //nc.addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_status,"pause",pendingIntent);

    //nc.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
    nc.setCustomBigContentView(expandView);



    setListners(expandView,context);
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_OPEN_ACTIVITY,nc.build());


}

private static void setListners(RemoteViews view,Context context){
    Intent previous=new Intent(NOTIFY_PREVIOUS);
    Intent next=new Intent(NOTIFY_NEXT);
    Intent play=new Intent(NOTIFY_PLAY);
    Intent pause=new Intent(NOTIFY_PAUSE);


    PendingIntent pPrevious=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, previous, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev,pPrevious);
    view.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_play, 1);



    PendingIntent pNext=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,next,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next,pNext);


    PendingIntent pPause=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,pause,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //view.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,R.id.status_bar_play);

    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_pause,pPause);
    view.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_pause,R.drawable.ic_play_status);
    view.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_pause,View.GONE);
    //view.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_pause,View.VISIBLE);
   //view.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_play,View.GONE);

    PendingIntent pPlay=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,play,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play,pPlay);
    view.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_play,View.VISIBLE);


    //view.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_prev,View.VISIBLE);


}
```

**NotificationReceiver Class**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   NotificationManager manger=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



   if(intent.getAction().equals(NotificationGenerator.NOTIFY_PLAY)){

       Intent playintent=new Intent();
       playintent.setAction("play");
       playintent.putExtra("playing",NotificationGenerator.NOTIFY_PLAY);
       context.sendBroadcast(playintent);

   }
   else if(intent.getAction().equals(NotificationGenerator.NOTIFY_PAUSE)) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


   }else if(intent.getAction().equals(NotificationGenerator.NOTIFY_NEXT)) {

       Intent nextintent=new Intent();
       nextintent.setAction("next");
       nextintent.putExtra("nexting",NotificationGenerator.NOTIFY_NEXT);
       context.sendBroadcast(nextintent);
   }else if(intent.getAction().equals(NotificationGenerator.NOTIFY_PREVIOUS)) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Previous", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

}

**Player.java class**

```
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction("play");
    //filternext.addAction("next");
    reciver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent !=null){
                   // if(intent.getStringExtra("play").equals("play")){
                        play();


                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.drawable.ic_play_status,R.drawable.ic_pause_status);
                    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_play,View.VISIBLE);

                }



        }
    };

    registerReceiver(reciver,filter);
    IntentFilter filternext=new IntentFilter();
    filternext.addAction("next");
    reciver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent!=null){
                next();
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(reciver,filternext);
```

> this is my code play and pause working but in notification bar not change the icon of play and pause button

Comment: I recommend putting logs for each broadcast receiver inside the onReceive method with the name of the broadcast receiver and the action from the intent. after that, you could narrow down the problem to a specific point in you code. do that and share the result.

Comment: all are working fine but when i click on pause notification button there is not change to play button @cmTiger

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand the issue, you can't affect the notification just by doing this

```
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.drawable.ic_play_status,R.drawable.ic_pause_status);
remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_play,View.VISIBLE);
```

You need to build the notification again:
[Update a notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Updating)